# Password visible while inspecting input element in a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Similar problems were seen on popular websites. Checkout the below image for reference

[Screenshot of login page of netflix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATDbq.jpg)

The value attribute of the input tag exposes the password, Is this an acceptable behaviour?

Comment: Yes this is an acceptable behaviour as only person typing the password can see it in DOM. Moreover the password is to be sent to the server for authentication hence it is not possible to send password without putting it into input value.